# app.yaml configuration to to shutdown the idle running instance for GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is there a parameter that can be used in .yaml file, which can turn off the google app engine running instance when idle for a specified time? The intention is to reduce the instance hours hence billing.

Comment: do you mean`idle` instead of `ideal`?

Comment: @DanCornilescu ..Yes, that was a typo. I am looking to run my app engine instance of my flask app during business hours and need to schedule it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option in app.yaml flex environment to stop instance if it is idle.
Flex should have atlease 1 instance running.

If you want to be billed for an instance, stop the instance manually or if you know the certain time when your app is not being used (e.g 6pm to 6am next day), you can schedule to stop / start instance version.

```
gcloud app versions stop v1
```

Comment: thanks Vikram, do you know how to schedule it? other than manually do it every time

Comment: @AkhilPakkath, you can use Cloud Scheduler

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule

Answer (score 1):

There is no `app.yaml` element that can stop an App Engine instance based on a condition for a specific amount of time.

The closest thing you can do to reduce costs using the `app.yaml` file, is to specify a cheaper, albeit less potent [**Instance Class**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) and / or reducing the [**resources**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) you assign to the instance, (depending on whether you’re using the **standard** or **flexible** environment respectively), as these are part of what you’re [billed for](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing).

Reducing the amount of instances you need is another approach; this can be done by lowering the value of `max_instances` and / or `max_idle_instances` in standard, and `max_num_instances` in flexible.

If you don’t want to be billed for an instance at all, you can stop the version associated to it with the `gcloud` command [`gcloud app versions stop`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/stop). In standard you won’t be charged when it’s stopped as it’s not running, but in flexible you will still pay for the disk size despite it.

A tool that can help you anticipate and estimate costs is the [Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/), where you can enter your desired configuration and see what would the costs approximately be. Setting up [budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#creating_budgets_and_setting_alerts) for when you reach a certain spending limit can be useful too. Similarly, in **standard**, you can [set a spending limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#setting_a_spending_limit), and when an application exceeds it, operations will consequently fail but you won't be billed for it.